# How to validate list box with jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using jquery validate and it works with the normal fields. I need a way to make sure there is at least one entry in the one listbox before validation is satisfied. I tried to add a custom method.

```
$.validator.addMethod('checklist', function(value, element) {
  if ($("#currentimp").val() ==""){
    return false;
    } else return true;
  }, "Listbox is empty");
```

Then in the rules i have the following:

```
currentimp: {
   checklist:true
}
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way to accomplish this but I haven't seen any good examples for what I'm trying to do. I also changed my form button to a submit button but it won't submit unless I add in a submit function to the submithandler. Is this normal?

Comment: Show the relevant _rendered_ HTML markup (as seen by the browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a listbox is some sort of select or radio, you can just use the `required:true` rule, no need to create your own custom rule.

Answer (score 1):

**Quote OP**:

> *"I need a way to make sure there is at least one entry in the one listbox before validation is satisfied."*

If by "listbox", you mean `<select multiple="multiple">`, then you do not need to write a custom method; you'd use the `required` rule.

The trick with validating a `select` is that your first `<option>` must contain `value=""`.

**HTML**:

```
<select name="currentimp" id="currentimp" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="">...</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            currentimp: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/5GKbF/**

---

**Quote OP**:

> *"I also changed my form button to a submit button but it won't submit unless I add in a submit function to the submithandler. Is this normal?"*

No, this is not normal.

The jQuery Validate plugin will always capture the click of any button with `type="submit"` as long as it's contained within your `<form></form>` tags.

Both `<input type="submit" ...` and `<button type="submit" ...` are acceptable.

The `submitHandler` callback is **not** a mandatory option.

If you leave out the `submitHandler` callback option, upon successful validation, the form will submit to the URL specified within your `action` attribute.

```
<form action="myScript.php" ...
```

Typically, the `submitHandler` is only used when you want to bypass the `action` and submit the form via `.ajax()`, and/or perform some other function(s).